# Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo to Colab

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo) topic suggests:

```
svn checkout https://github.com/lodash/lodash/trunk/test
```

But it doesn't work in Colab. I tried to install svn:

```
!pip install tsvn
```

It returns an error:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py
> egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Is there another way to download a folder from github?

Comment: Please checkout this well documented problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo

Comment: There is no answer. I've already mentioned this in my post.

Comment: Sorry for missing your link. I was confused because in the post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59100287/3068214 it mentioned that there are several different ways to do it but I only see that you've tried using SVN approach. Also, what is the problem that you are exactly facing? Unable to download the library tsvn? Or using the library?

Comment: Everything there returns an error. If you managed to download a folder from github to colab write your example here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `pip`, use `apt` instead

```
!apt install subversion
```

Then you can checkout normally

```
!svn checkout https://github.com/lodash/lodash/trunk/test
```

Answer (score 0):

Colab uses Linux machine in the backend so use **apt** instead of **pip**

[subversion colab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OryPW.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).