# downloading only a specific folder from git hub

Tags: git, github

I want to download a specific folder from github using git command.
I have tried many things.recent was below

```
cd <dir>
git init
git remote add origin -f <URL>
git config core.sparseCheckout true # enable this
cat >> .git/info/sparsecheckout
<folder>
git pull origin master
```

but no luck, entire repo got downloaded.
can anyone help with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+clone+single+folder

Comment: Nothing Answers my question. i tried them . In sparsecheckout we have to add the local server path right not the github path right?