# clone a single folder from o github repository

Tags: github

I am trying to download a single folder from a github repo. Is there a way to do this without downloading the complete repository?

The folder in question is located on https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-mvc-basics.

Answer (score 1):

1. Head over to https://downgit.github.io/#/home
2. Paste in your giving folder link
3. Click download
4. Extract the zip to a place your like it to be
5. Done!

Read more:

- [Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo)