# VS Code - OSS: Downloading files and folders to desktop

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

As the title implies, I use Code OSS for some development.

Is there a way I can download a file, folder or even the whole solution to my desktop easily?
The only option i have encountered so far is to have to GIT Push/Pull the entire solution which is really cumbersome, especially if I only need 1 folder.

Comment: What do you mean by downloading a file/folder? Are you talking about downloading a file/folder from a remote git repository instead of cloning the whole repository?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [GitZip](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gitzip-for-github/ffabmkklhbepgcgfonabamgnfafbdlkn) browser extension. It will be helpful for downloading specific files and folder without having to `git clone` the entire solution.

The usage is very simple:

1. Install the extension using given link.
2. Get an access token by clicking the extensions icon near the address bar.
3. Browse to any GitHub repo and right-click the blank section near any file/folder and click "Download ***folder/file name*** as zip".

It works great in most cases where the number of nested files and folders is less than 1000 due to GitHub Trees API limitation.

[image]

Comment: I need to download the file/folder from Code OSS not from Github. I'm not sure this solves what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not support downloading a specific folder.

But you can achieve this using Github subversion support.

#### Steps

1. Install [svn](https://subversion.apache.org/). For example, [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html).
2. Install [SVN extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnstoncode.svn-scm) in Code.
3. Open Command Palette in Code (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` or `Cmd`+`Shift`+`P`) and type `svn:checkout` and hit `Enter` to run the checkout command.
4. Enter the path of the Git folder you want to download replacing the path's `tree/master` part with `trunk` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194523/4453794).

For example, if you want to download the **packages** folder in the **vue-next** repository, `https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/tree/master/packages` will be the Github URL for the folder.

Replace the `tree/master` part with `trunk`: `https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/trunk/packages`. This will be your SVN checkout path you'll enter in the svn checkout dialog in Code.

5. Select a local repository location to checkout.

This is probably too much for downloading a folder. But writing this as you wanted a way to download a folder from Code itself.
I didn't find any Code extension that could achieve this directly.

And I personally think that [Mikaal Anwar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6866739/mikaal-anwar)'s solution is a better one if you want to do it from a browser instead of from VSCode.

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194523/4453794

Comment: The question was never about git. I have a browser-based version of Code OSS (the open source layer of vs code) and i want to download a folder from it. without resorting to git.

AFAIK i still have to push to git in both solutions