# sparse checkout subfolders in mono repo in on-premise bitbucket server using AWS CodeBuild/pipeline

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, bitbucket-api

''''
I am trying to integrate bitbucket with aws codebuild/pipeline and realized it's not so straight forward like aws code commit or git hub enterprise. Somehow, achieved the integration using API gateways, lambda and bitbucket web hook triggers(pay loads). However, Not able to understand how to do "sparse checkout of a folder under a mono repo in bit bucket server through aws codeBuild".

We have a working lambda which is at present checking out the entire repo from BB to S3 bucket via API gateway. need to understand the way to get sparse checkout of sub folder in a mono repo whenevr a developer commits which further triggers code build in aws", I feel the lambda has to be customized to do so, great if anyone share the lambda code(any scripting language used) or method followed to address the scenario
''''

Comment: Is it possible to use the git CLI as part of the `clone` step? If so, see my answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo/65911352#65911352)

Comment: I am not sure cli solution may not work to call / check out the bitbucket(on premise server) sub folders(mono repo) via aws lambda to run aws codebuild. Can the cli solution of yours be integrated to the lambda?

Comment: I'm here - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228351/sparse-checkout