# GitHub repo is showing extra folders that my local repo doesn't

Tags: git, github

I have a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/rayrfan/Fanray) that shows extra folders as shown in the picture below, each of the 3 folders highlighted do contain one or more files and folders in them, and these 3 folders are supposed to be inside the folders their paths are dictating.

But, when I checkout the repo to my local, these 3 folders are at where they ought to be and I don't see these extra folders dangling outside. So, does anyone know what's causing this disparity and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: This is going to be one of those Windows upper/lowercase sensitivity questions, isn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks to the other two answers, they pointed out the casing issue which I had not encountered before but now I know. Here are the specific steps I took to solve my problem.

1. Delete the three folders and all their content "Plugins", "Themes" and "Widgets"
2. Commit with these folders and files missing
3. Copy back the folders I just deleted
4. Commit again to add them back

Answer (score 0):

Look closely: the "dangling" directories are all in lower-case ("plugins", "themes", "widgets") and the "correct" directories are mixed case ("Plugins", "Themes", "Widgets").

In git, and in some file systems, those are different names. However, in Windows, directory names are case insensitive, so when you check out the code on Windows, the "Plugins" and "plugins" directories get merged together.

You'll need to check out somewhere that preserves the case, and rename the lower-case versions to the correct form.