# Download files from multiple github repos into a new project

Tags: git, github, curl, svn, wget

I'm working on developing an app using the Celer Bridge API. They have multiple repos, ([client](https://github.com/celer-network/cBridge-typescript-client) and [transfer widget](https://github.com/celer-network/cBridge-transfer-widget/tree/main)) which I need to download files from to add to my react project. I've been using `svn checkout` to download the files. However, both projects use the `proto` folder, and trying to download from two repos causes error `svn: E155000` since `proto` is already a working copy from a different URL.

I'm aware I could pipe `curl` to `tar` like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51962069/2028236). If possible I'd prefer to just download the folder directly, rather than having to extract specific folders.

In the long term, I'd probably want to set these up as submodules, and run a script to update the remote repo. However, for now I just want to download the folders to my computer. Is there any means of downloading project folders directly using tools like `curl` or `wget`?

Comment: You can't download a whole folder from a single URL.  That's what archives like tarballs and zip files are for.

Comment: I've managed to download a single file before. There's really no means of downloading a directory too?

Comment: Outside of an archive, there isn't.  That's why I recommended an archive.

Comment: Couldn't I scrape the site? Have a script that drills down through directories, and downloads individual files with curl or wget?

Comment: An archive is easier and more robust than scraping, since it's a programmatic interface for getting the data you want.  You can choose to extract only the files you want from the archive.  In addition, scraping the website or the raw file endpoints will get you rate-limited with a 429, so it won't work in the general case.