# Clone a subfolder of a repository, without cloning the entire project

Tags: git, svn, repository, subdirectory, git-clone

I need to copy/clone only this folder with all its files:
https://github.com/raycast/extensions/tree/main/extensions/github

I found the following solution, the one that recommends using svn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39317180/8024296

But I don't know which svn is best to install from brew, which of these is best to use:

`subversion` or `git-svn`, do you think?

If you have any other better solution in 2023 instead of using svn, they are welcome.

Comment: Do you want just download the tree, or have a working git repo too?

Comment: If you just want to download, see [Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7106012/11082165). If you want a clone, then sparse and shallow checkouts is the best you can do.

Comment: @Brian61354270: I just want to have the github folder, with its files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo)